# Is there a 'restart' function in Windows/C++

Tags: c++, windows, restart

In a windows project I am working on, I intend to have a menu selection that copletely restarts the app.  Is there a Windows or C++ function that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built-in for this, but a well-designed application can simply stop everything that's going on and then loop back to the start. If you want a true 'fresh start', you will have to spawn a new process (possibly as the last thing you do before the old one shuts down.)

Comment: Thanx, could you elaborate a little more on spawning a new process? (I'm fairly new to windows programming)

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463040/does-windows-have-its-own-call-other-exe-function-c

Answer (score 2):

No, you must do it yourself. 
For instance, you can run external process which will wait until you exit your application, and then run it again.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you might want to take a look at the Restart Manager API that came in with Windows Vista. As ever you can p-invoke this to your hearts content and theirs explicit support coming for it in [Visual C++ 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/02/18/mfc-restart-manager.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Already needed to do this. The easiest way without any further reading would be to write a simple .bat-file (either by hand or dynamically by your application)  starting your program and then calling that bat-file from your application.

The bat-file may even contain a line to remove itself after having started your app...

Answer (score 0):

You want to call [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) and then close your current instance of the application gracefully with [ExitProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682658(VS.85).aspx), or if you link to the C runtime, just return from main().
But first you should ask yourself why you need to recreate the process in the first place.

Answer (score -3):

[ExitWindowsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868(VS.85).aspx)  is what you want. You can also run the [shutdown.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317371) utility built into windows.

```
shutdown -t0 -r (restart the system after 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Leaving in case it is needed by anyone else :D

Comment: Keand64 wants to restart application, not the whole system.

Comment: Technically, if he puts his app in the Run key or in the startup folder, this will restart his app.