# Does Windows have its own 'call other .exe' function (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, system, running-other-programs

I know in C++ there is a function

```
system("example.exe");
```

that runs another program, put it requires the include `stdlib.h`.

Because I am already including 'windows.h', is there an equivilant to the `system()` function in Windows?

Comment: Actually, since this has a "C++" tag, it's `std::system()` and `<csdtlib>`.

Comment: Actually, since this has a "C++" tag, there is a function `system` defined in the root namespace in the `<stdlib.h>` header. You may prefer the other way of including it (like any sensible C++ programmer), that's up to you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) to run a specific executable, or [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) to run programs or open documents with their associated program.

If portability to other platforms is any issue at all, I'd stick with system. #including stdlib.h won't kill you ;)

Answer (score 4):

Check the [MSDN page for CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) for more information

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for CreateProcess?